# How to cacth 'hidden.bs.modal' in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5.6

I want to handle event `hidden.bs.modal` to clear data in variable.

But it seem like not working anymore.

```
<template>
    <div id="my_modal"
         class="modal"
         tabindex="-1"
         role="dialog"
         aria-hidden="true"
         ref="my_modal">
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            $(this.$refs.my_modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', this.doSomething());
        },

        methods: {
            doSomething() {
                // Do something
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need parenthesis after doSomething. You want to pass function itself, not a result of it

```
 mounted() {
     $(this.$refs.my_modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', this.doSomething);
 },
```

Comment: and how it didnt worked? What errors do u have in console?

Comment: @ThunderBirdsX3 u are doing something other wrong then.  Here is working example with code : https://codepen.io/aldarund/pen/bjeORz?editors=1010
But if u can i recommend to use vue bootstrap e.g. https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/

Comment: Yes, It have some thing wrong. I used `laravel-mix` and this problem come from that package. More details here https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1720